# Mui Data-Grid-Pro table with expandable rows: How to make rows expanded by default and how to change one of literals

Tags: mui-x-data-grid

I use very, very simplified table ith expandable rows
This is basically the example shown here:https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/tree-data/

Really, I do not need much more. However, would like to change two aspects ( I understand that limited customization ability is a tradeoff for simplicity).

1. I'd like to have rows expanded by default
2. I would like to replace "Groups" literal by something else

Spent some time with dosc but examples are with generally much more advanced versions.
However, maybe ther is a way to achieve the goals keeping things simple?

Please have critical parts of my code here:
That is how the table is rendered.

```
return (
    <>
      <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGridPro
          treeData
          rows={checklistRows}
          columns={aColumns}
          getTreeDataPath={getTreeDataPath}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Row items are more or less like in original

```
{
hierarchy: ['Mary', 'Linda', 'William'],
jobTitle: 'Back-end developer',
recruitmentDate: new Date(2018, 4, 19),
id: 14,
   },
```

If you need something else, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

For First point, you can use
**defaultGroupingExpansionDepth={-1}**

This will keep all rows expanded by default.

For Second point, you can use **groupingColDef** prop
and define custom header name using **renderHeader**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).